# Generating a random variable in R through a function

Tags: r

How can I write a function in R that will generate a random variable that returns a beta distributed variable inputting the following data `alpha = .123, beta = 2.77` and `runif` (to generate a uniformly distributed number between 0 and 1)?

I just want to type a number inside the parentheses and get such number of variables with the given distribution following the distribution `42 * rbeta(runif, alpha, beta)`.

Comment: The beta distribution (as implemented in R) has two parameters, alpha and beta, plus an optional non-centrality parameter. So what is your `runif` here? In R, `rbeta(n, .123, 2.77)` will return `n` values from that distribution, and it doesn't make sense to have `n` between 0 and 1...

Comment: as i undestand it that first parameter  is one of the imput values from in the function just like ALPHA and BETA. then, or what is the meaning of that value

Comment: the first argument is the number of random deviates you want the function to return. See `?rbeta`: `n: number of observations.`

Comment: the answer is `my_fun <- function(n) 42*rbeta(n, alpha, beta)` ...

Answer (score 0):

So what I think you mean is how do you create a function from this function and variable into which you pass a number which reflects the specific values of alpha and beta defined above, here is a simple way of doing this:

#### Create the function

```
betaFunction <- function(n){
a = .123
b = 2.77
x = rbeta(n, b, a)
return(x)
}
```

#### now give it a test drive!

```
betaData <- betaFunction(17)
 [1] 1.0000000 0.8376054 0.9741555 0.9999962 1.0000000 0.9953391
 [7] 0.6217407 0.9661690 0.9961457 0.8209120 0.8538891 0.9146376
[13] 0.9781314 1.0000000 0.9999437 0.9737847 0.9999995
```